# @media Query to resize image is only working on page refresh

Tags: browser, responsive-design, media-queries

Here is my @media query:

```
@media (max-height: 950px) {
#menu_img {
    height: 800px;
    width: 400px;
}
}
```

The query works, but only when I refresh the page.  The changes do not happen while I am re-sizing the browser.  I have to re-size, then refresh the page.  It is happening in chrome, and the query doesn't work at all in Firefox or IE.  I am mystified as to why.

I have also tried adding:

```
@media screen and (max-height: 950px)
```

and also

```
@media only screen and (max-height: 950px)
```

The site can be viewed here:  http://simonmoonlandings.com if you need to see the full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a viewport tag, i.e. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">`. You also need to remove the inline width on the `img` and add `width: 100%` to the `img` via CSS. Finally, remove any px widths in your CSS and replace them with percentages.

Comment: Ok so I set the px to %  for all containers, and removed the inline images sizes, and set image size to % via css, and added viewport tag and it is still not resizing until I refresh the page.

Comment: I'm assuming you didn't push those changes up because the site you referenced doesn't reflect that. I threw together a [demo page](http://jsbin.com/ohewov/1/edit), you can see what I'm talking about there.

Comment: Found the problem, it was a jquery that affected im image map tied to the image, adding $(window).resize(function() solved it.

Comment: Will you expand more on what you mean by that? Maybe in the question or in a full answer? I also had that same issue of an image-map highlighter jQuery script preventing an image from resizing.